# Approaches on how to layout an image that spans two different background images

Tags: html, css

Looking for some hints and tips on how I could implement the design below in html/css:

[image]

The candle is an image. The green background is a tiled background of a div that contains other elements while the pink background is the background of the whole page.

How do I put the candle image in such a way that the most of it is inside the div with the green bg and then the small protruding part of the fire has for its bg the pink pattern? Note that the pink patten is the bg for the whole page.

The green image

Comment: Needs more info. Will the green background be repeated to the right? What widths will there be? Will the candle always stick to the left hand side? What aspect of doing this is your question about exactly?

Comment: The candle will always stick to the left hand side. To its right, not show in the image, are two other icons like it that are within the bounds of the green div.

Comment: okay, but you're still not saying what your question is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the candle a transparent PNG file so I don't have to go through the hassle of building a candle image that has the stripes and dots of the background images aligned correctly.

That may create issues in IE6 if you use alpha transparency, but there are workarounds for that.

Then I'd place the candle in a container with `float: left` or `position: absolute` (Depending on the rest of the layout), positioned to the left hand side of the green area.

The image itself would then get `position: relative; top: -50px` (adjust accordingly) to move up outside the content container.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/TtPxC/).

For the image, you need a transparent png or gif file to look though at the green and pink pattern.